# How to import socket.io on client side - SOCKET.IO + NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have been trying to create an online game but when I try to use `socket.on(...);` or `socket.emit(...)` it comes up with an error like what is `socket`. I have seen some posts similar to this one and tried all the solutions but none worked. I have already got `io.connect(...);` working and it works (I assume this means I have properly set up socket.io-client). I just don't see what I am doing wrong. If you need the code you can simply request it though I don't think it was necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use SocketIO on the client-side, first import it via

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

Then, probably in a constructor, establish a connection to the server's ip and port running the SocketIO server

```
const socket = io(`172.16.1.3:81`);
```

Also in the constructor you will likely want to setup a function to be called when the server sends a certain message type:

```
socket.on("update-player", handlePlayerUpdateFunction);
```

and

```
function handlePlayerUpdateFunction(message) {
    console.log(`Received message from server: ${message}`);
}
```

If this client does not receive the message sent from your server, then something is wrong with your server not being set up correctly to listen on the port.

Comment: the 'socket' variable is not defined? if so then something is wrong with your server and its not listening on the port

Answer (score 1):

After trying some things and doing some research I found the solution to my problem. Adding in `var socket = io.connect(x.x.x.x:3000);` my code started functioning and everything was perfect I had already imported socket.io-client trough CDNJS link on the installation guide. I just had to Initialise the variable.