# Javascript Import is not working as it should

Tags: javascript

I installed `socket.io-client` dependency and when I tried to import it it gave me this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument
```

Here is the code:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");

function createNewMessage() {
  const getInputById = document.getElementById("message_input");
  const createSpan = document.createElement("p");
  createSpan.innerHTML = getInputById.value;
  createSpan.className = "message";
  getInputById.value = "";
  document
    .getElementsByClassName("messanger_main_container")[0]
    .appendChild(createSpan);
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are you running this with Node.JS? Which version?

Comment: if `es6` is not supported, you should use like `const io = require("socket.io-client");`

Comment: That's a very odd error message, I would have expected something like "`import` statements can only be used in modules." It seems to think that your `import` is the `import` pseudo-function from dynamic import, but it isn't, it's a correctly-formatted static `import` statement. How are you running the code? In a browser? If so, do you have `type="module"` on the `script` for the code?

Comment: I tried using require but it gave error that require is not defined

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am actually importing it as a script in my html. I installed it and I am trying to import it from node modules

Comment: You may need to use a bundler like Webpack or Rollup.

Comment: @Acidic9 Okay I will try to set up webpack

Comment: What do you mean by *" I am actually importing it as a script in my html."*? Remember there are two completely separate environments here, the code running on the server (which may be using Node.js) and the code running on the browser (which isn't, it's running in a browser).

Comment: I am running it in the browser

Answer (score -1):

Try importing like this

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274250/how-to-import-socket-io-on-client-side-socket-io-node-js) for more info.